# Get lat long for address in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to find the lat long corresponding to the a series of values. These values are a concatenation of merchant name and address(address obtained from google maps).

However when i try to find the url corresponding to these address, multiple stores are coming, some of which dont even belong to that pincode.

I am running the below  code in python

```
data_1['Url_With_Coordinates'] = None

for index, row in tqdm(data_1.iterrows(), total=len(data_1), leave=False):
    url = row['Url']
    
    # Check if the URL is not missing or blank
    if url and not pd.isna(url):
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            meta_element = driver.find_element('css selector', 'meta[itemprop=image]')
            content_attribute = meta_element.get_attribute('content')
            data_1.at[index, 'Url_With_Coordinates'] = content_attribute
        except:
            pass

# Close the driver and service
driver.quit()
service.stop()
```

If we run the above for Arrow store located at Shop No 18, UGF, Orion Mall, 80 Feet Road, Dr ajkumar Road, Malleswaram, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560055 using the url https://www.google.com/maps/search/Arrow Shop No 18, UGF, Orion Mall, 80 Feet Road, Dr ajkumar Road, Malleswaram, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560055, the driver fetches multiple arrow stores some of which dont even belong to this pincode